# vim treats register as comment when using the :normal command

Tags: vim

I'm using the terminal version of vim.
When I execute:

```
:normal 0"+d$
```

it doesn't cut the line into the `+` register. Instead it just executes the `0`; it moves to the beginning of the line, and that's it. It seems to ignore whatever is after the `"` character.
If I do `:normal 0d$` it works fine.

Any ideas what might be causing this? I had this in a function in my .vimrc and didn't have any issues (with gvim). Now when I tried it in the terminal (on Solaris) it fails.

Comment: It's possible that the non-gvim version was compiled without clipboard support. Use the `:version` command to see what options are enabled.

Comment: ah, that was it...it only igores the + registry, thanks. You can add it as an answer I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clipboard support in vim is an optional feature that can be disabled at compile time. It can be enabled independently of the gui, but often isn't. In a non-gvim version of vim it is more likely that you don't have clipboard support, so the `"+` register doesn't exist.

`:version` should show `+clipboard` or `-clipboard` to indicate whether the feature is enabled.

If you type `"+` command while actually *in* normal mode, you should get an error bell if the feature is disabled.